# Range of validity of geometric optics misstatement in University Physics

Tags: geometric-optics, textbook-erratum

University physics claims in a discourse regarding electron microscopy that,

> Geometric optics is valid whenever interference and diffraction effects can be neglected

And I struggle to interpret this on a few counts,

- By the book's own admission, interference and diffraction are the same phenomena, with diffraction being caused by interference
- This also seems to discount descriptions and analyses of certain types of scattering.

  - That is, in an analysis of x-ray crystallography, the type of scattering observed reproduced the law of reflection off the tangent, rather than the normal.

Can anyone help me with the words here?

*Young, H. D., Freedman, R. A., & Ford, L. (2007). University physics with modern physics (12th ed.). Pearson.*

Comment: [Geometrical Optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_optics) describes light propagation in terms of rays. [Diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction) and [Interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_interference) require the notion of a wave. Where is there  now an erratum ?

Comment: Ah well, at second glance I seem to have read a bijection into that. Thanks!